# Parent CSS hierarchy needed

Tags: css, reactjs

```
div#foo {

    body {
        background-color: white;
        font-size: 20px;
    }

}
```

Above is what I want. This is a css file. Basically my app div in react has an id foo and I want the css to only apply the tags in that div. Is there anyway to get this ?

This would solve a major issue with my code. Currently I have 2 react js files. One of them imported the above css the other did not yet for some reason they both are using the same style while I just want the file that actually imported to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `index.html` file, inside the `<head></head>`, you can add this:

```
<style>
    body {
        background-color: white;
        font-size: 20px;
    }
</style>
```

You shouldn't be nesting your `body` tag inside of a `div`. So if it's not working and your DOM structure is actually correct, it's because your CSS is incorrectly targeting the body, as it's looking for the body as a child of a div.

Alternatively, if you import the stylesheet with your body styles into your App.js (your React root), it should automatically append those styles to the document head.

Comment: Oh I just realised that. Do I put div in place for body in react? I'm trying to port my html code to react js

Comment: Nah, you'll want to keep the body tag. Just place the div inside the body.